# UITabbarController replace the last view controller

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller

I need replace the last view controller, depending on the condition. Into `TabBarController` I have 4 view controllers, last view controller it's `LoginVC`. If I'm already logged in I need replace `LoginVC` to `ProfileVC`.

I try:

```
 func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, shouldSelect viewController: UIViewController) -> Bool {
    if tabBarController.selectedIndex == 3 && !DefaultsManager.instance.getUserToken().isEmpty {
        showProfile()
        return false
    }
    return true
}

func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, didSelect viewController: UIViewController) {
    if tabBarController.selectedIndex == 3 && !DefaultsManager.instance.getUserToken().isEmpty {
        showProfile()
    }
}

 func showProfile() {
    let profile = ProfileVC.instantiateNCFromStoryboard()
    self.viewControllers?[3] = profile
}
```

But it's does't work for me.

screen with login screen [image]

screen profile screen with my condition

[image]

Comment: Please add your showProfie()  code.

Comment: @BhaveshSarsawa update questions

Comment: on last tab you can create controller which on viewWillAppear will detect is your user authorized or not, and perform vc you need without animation. Read about pattern state))

Comment: @ИсмаилХасбулатов Do you have all view controllers in storyboard?

Comment: @RajeshKumarR yes

Comment: Не так, на последнем Табе контроллер который выступает как посредник, только для определения куда идти дальше, в нем определяем на какой экран нужно перейти и делаем переход без анимации. Для простоты можно использовать контейнер, как вариант, можно нарисовать 2 view и подгрузить нужную в контроллер в зависимости от состояния (authorized/nonAuthorized)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `AppDelegate` check user login status and change the last view controller and its `tabBarItem`

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    if let rootVC = self.window?.rootViewController as? UITabBarController, var viewControllers = rootVC.viewControllers {
        viewControllers.removeLast()
        if userLoggedIn {
            let profileVC = ProfileVC()
            //profileVC.tabBarItem = UITabBarItem(title: nil, image: UIImage(named: "imgName"), selectedImage: UIImage(named: "imgName"))
            profileVC.tabBarItem = UITabBarItem(title: "Profile", image: nil, selectedImage: nil)
            viewControllers.append(profileVC)
        } else {
            let loginVC = LoginVC()
            //loginVC.tabBarItem = UITabBarItem(title: nil, image: UIImage(named: "imgName"), selectedImage: UIImage(named: "imgName"))
            loginVC.tabBarItem = UITabBarItem(title: "Login", image: nil, selectedImage: nil)
            viewControllers.append(loginVC)
        }
        rootVC.viewControllers = viewControllers
    }
    return true
}
```

In `LoginVC` upon successfull login, remove `LoginVC` from `tabBarController` and add `ProfileVC`

```
@objc func loginBtnAction(_ sender: UIButton) {
    if var viewControllers = self.tabBarController?.viewControllers {
        viewControllers.removeLast()
        let profileVC = ProfileVC()
        //profileVC.tabBarItem = UITabBarItem(title: nil, image: UIImage(named: "imgName"), selectedImage: UIImage(named: "imgName"))
        profileVC.tabBarItem = UITabBarItem(title: "Profile", image: nil, selectedImage: nil)
        viewControllers.append(profileVC)
        self.tabBarController?.viewControllers = viewControllers
    }
}
```

In `Logout` button action from `ProfileVC`, remove `ProfileVC` from `tabBarController` and add `LoginVC`

```
@objc func logoutBtnAction(_ sender: UIButton) {
    if var viewControllers = self.tabBarController?.viewControllers {
        viewControllers.removeLast()
        let loginVC = LoginVC()
        //loginVC.tabBarItem = UITabBarItem(title: nil, image: UIImage(named: "imgName"), selectedImage: UIImage(named: "imgName"))
        loginVC.tabBarItem = UITabBarItem(title: "Login", image: nil, selectedImage: nil)
        viewControllers.append(loginVC)
        self.tabBarController?.viewControllers = viewControllers
    }
}
```